# Redux Persist - cannot read property of null (reading 'user')

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

Hello everyone I am trying to build an E-commerce project using MERN but I have some difficulties with `redux-persist`.

In the `App.jsx` the `useSelector` does not read the `user` from state

```
Property 'user' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'
```

Also, in `requestMethod` TOKEN does not read the `user`, it says "cannot read property of null ("user"). Before using `redux-persist`, the register and login worked.

I posted the code I think there are some bugs but if you think the problems come from somewhere else I can add those files too. Thank you!

Package.json

```json
 "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "json-server": "^0.16.3",
    "mongodb": "^4.1.3",
    "mongoose": "^6.0.9",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-modal": "^3.14.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reduxjs-toolkit-persist": "^7.0.7",
    "shortid": "^2.2.16",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
```

Index.jsx

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store, persistor } from "./redux/store";
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.jsx

```js
const App = () => {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser);
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Home/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/products/:category">
          <ProductList/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/product/:id">
          <Product />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/cart">
          <Cart/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/success">
          <Success/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/login">
          {user ? <Redirect to ="/"/> : <Login/>}
          <Login/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/register">
        {user ? <Redirect to ="/"/> : <Register/>}
```

state.user

```
Object
cart:
products: []
quantity: 0
total: 0
[[Prototype]]: Object
user:
currentUser: {_id: '616001631a1375942f6d7dd9', username: 'admin', email: 'admin@gmail.com', isAdmin: true, createdAt: '2021-10-08T08:29:23.827Z', …}
error: false
isFetching: false
[[Prototype]]: Object
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
__proto__: (...)
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
_persist:
rehydrated: true
version: 1
[[Prototype]]: Object
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
__proto__: (...)
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
[[Prototype]]: Object
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
__proto__: (...)
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

Store.js

```js
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import cartReducer from "./cartRedux";
import userReducer from "./userRedux";
import {
    persistStore,
    persistReducer,
    FLUSH,
    REHYDRATE,
    PAUSE,
    PERSIST,
    PURGE,
    REGISTER,
} from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";


const persistConfig = {
    key: "root",
    version: 1,
    storage,
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ user: userReducer, cart: cartReducer })

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);


export const store = () => configureStore({
    reducer:
        persistedReducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware({
            serializableCheck: {
                ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
            },
        })
})


export let persistor = persistStore(configureStore);
```

requestMethods.js

```js
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/";
const TOKEN =
    JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('persist:root')).user).currentUser
        .accessToken || "";

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

export const userRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    header: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` },
});
```

User Redux

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "user",
    initialState: {
        currentUser: null,
        isFetching: false,
        error: false,
    },
    reducers: {
        loginStart: (state) => {
            state.isFetching = true;
        },
        loginSuccess: (state, action) => {
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.currentUser = action.payload;
        },
        loginFailure: (state) => {
            state.isFetching = false;
            state.error = true;
        },
    },
});

export const { loginStart, loginSuccess, loginFailure } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Where do you wrap your App component with the redux provider?

Comment: @novonimo Hi! The problem went away by itself but then it came back, still have not solved it. I added the index.js where the redux provider is.

Comment: I try in console: fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/")  and it returns GET 404 ( not found )

Comment: In your **App** component, what is the result of `const user = useSelector(state => state)`? please change the selector and log the result on user .  I'm looking for your whole state object to prove everything with your redux store is working correctly.

Comment: the reason for the second problem with your `token` is now clear to me. I'm waiting for the above answer to post my answer

Comment: @novonimo I added const user = useSelector((state) => state);
 console.log(user) and posted the log above after App.jsx code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some little issues with your implementation. let's review them:

First, you are getting the `user` object from the state with a selector, your `user` variable (in `App` component) is now an object.

```
const yourStateObject = {
  user: {
    currentUser: {_id: '616001631a1375942f6d7dd9', username: 'admin', email: 'admin@gmail.com', isAdmin: true, createdAt: '2021-10-08T08:29:23.827Z', ...}
  }
}
```

Now, take a look at result of your selector:

```
const user = useSelector(state => state.user.currentUser)

console.log(user) // {_id: '616001631a1375942f6d7dd9', username: 'admin', email: 'admin@gmail.com', isAdmin: true, createdAt: '2021-10-08T08:29:23.827Z', ...}
```

##### The Problem

So far, so good, but in the `Router` you are trying to check the `user` object with the ternary operator.

consider this example:

```
const myObject = {}

console.log(myObject ? "Yes this is an object" : "Nothing exist") 

console.log(myAnotherObject ? "Yes this is an object" : "Nothing exist")
```

since the `myObject` is defined, the left side of the ternary result will be returned, but in the second `console.log`, the right side will be returned because the `myAnotherObject` is not defined and evaluated as `undefined`.

##### The Solution

instead of evaluating the `user` object to return the correct route, check for the user id or username.

```
const userId = useSelector(state => state.user.currentUser._id)

return (
  // rest of the codes ...
  {userId ? <Redirect to ="/"/> : <Login/>}
  // rest of the codes ...
)
```

Also, you need to use `{}` as `initialState` in `userSlice` instead of `null`

```
const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "user",
    initialState: {
        currentUser: {},   // ------> here
        isFetching: false,
        error: false,
    },
   // rest of the codes ...
```

##### Token

you are getting the token from the persistor storage, which is not correct.
instead of retrieving the token from the persistor storage, save it on the localStorage directly and then get it when needed.

```
// set token
localStorage.setItem('ACCESS_TOKEN', token);

// get token
const myToken = localStorage.getItem('ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! I will implement asap and post the outcome :)

Comment: It's my pleasure @MariusPetrut . I'm waiting for your response about the implementation, feel free to ask questions.

Comment: You were right that solved the problem! Much appreciation